# show a login page before moving to main app in xamarin.android

Tags: xamarin.android, navigation-drawer, android-dialogfragment

so I'm trying to make an android app that starts with a login page (that I thought could be a dialog fragment) and if the user's credentials are correct, then he'll be directed to the main app that is supposed to be a navigation drawer app. I tried to use the dialog fragment but I didn't know how to set it to appear at the very beginning. what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a Activity as a `MainLauncher`, Activity you can use a blank `Layout.xml` like following code, then pop a DialogFragment like following code. Note: you should add `MainLauncher = true,NoHistory =true` in your `Activity` attribute. `NoHistory =true` will make the back button navigate to the desktop.

```
namespace App2
{
    [Activity(Label = "LoginActivity", Theme = "@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar",MainLauncher = true,NoHistory =true)]
    public class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity, OnLoginInforCompleted
    {
        public void inputLoginInforCompleted(string userName, string passWord)
        {
            //You can get the username and password here
            StartActivity(new Intent(this,typeof(MainActivity)));
        }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LoginLayout);
           
            MyDialogFragment dialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
            dialogFragment.setOnLoginInforCompleted(this);
            dialogFragment.Cancelable = false;
            var SupportFragmentManager = this.FragmentManager;
            dialogFragment.Show(SupportFragmentManager, "dialog");
            
        }
    }
}
```

I achieve the a callback interface `OnLoginInforCompleted`, If User click the Login Button, will navigate to the  navigation drawer page.

```
 public interface OnLoginInforCompleted
    {
        void inputLoginInforCompleted(String userName, String passWord);
    }
```

Here is code about `MyDialogFragment` .

```
    public class MyDialogFragment : DialogFragment
    {
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.layout3, container, false);
            Button button = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
            EditText MyeditText1 = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
            EditText MyeditText2 = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText2);
            button.Click += delegate {
                //set the data to the loginpage
                mOnLoginInforCompleted.inputLoginInforCompleted(MyeditText1.Text.ToString(), MyeditText2.Text.ToString());
              
                Dismiss();
            };
            return view;
            
        }

        //set for Callback
        private OnLoginInforCompleted mOnLoginInforCompleted;
        public void setOnLoginInforCompleted(OnLoginInforCompleted onLoginInforCompleted)
        {
            mOnLoginInforCompleted = onLoginInforCompleted;
        }

        public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            return base.OnCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        }
    }
```

Here is running GIF.

[image]

Here is my demo, you can refer to it.

https://github.com/851265601/Xamarin.Android_ListviewSelect/blob/master/App2.zip

Comment: thanks a lot sir for the answer, it was very helpful. if I want to check the credentials before logging in via a webservice, I should do this inside the button click event right? should I replace the " mOnLoginInforCompleted.inputLoginInforCompleted". I've been trying to do this but it's not working with me. thanks a lot again